# Tableview cell offset

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I am trying to do something similar to the picture down bellow in my current project.

**Question one**, how do I add some `offset` between the `tableview` `cells`? like on the picture.

**Question two**, how do I make that askew overlay?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using `UITableHeaderFootView` for each spacing. That is, each section in your table view will be a spacer. Then you give each section a height based on the amount of space you need.

I'm not sure what you mean by askew overlay.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer given by sdasdadas should work. But what I would recommend instead is to just make your cell a little bigger and increase the padding on each side from the inner view.

if you want your view to have a height for 100 for example, make the height of your cell 120 and give it a 10 padding on top and 10 padding below. 
If you want 20 padding, make the cell 140 and give it 20 padding on top and below.

Note : Just my way of doing it.